# Javascript Split string into multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to split a string into a javascript multi-dimensional array. Assistance or pointers would he hugely appreciated.

String consists of 3 fields - comma delimiter for each field, and # delimiter for each record

Data/String:

Big Ben,www.myurl.com,2020-10-03#Buckingham Palace,www.myurl2.com,2020-15-03#

thank you in advance.

Comment: This website doesnt provide code to you. We help solving the issues you have with the code. So please show us what you have tried and where you encouter a problem...

[look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry - I thought that this was a community that provided assistance ? I've worked with single arrays before, but not sure how to work with multi-dimensional arrays and splitting

Comment: [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971189/create-a-js-multidimensional-array-from-string) try to apply the answers to your problem. If you are stuck then we can help. Now someone is providing a answer and you dont learn anything from it by just copy pasting it...

Comment: You must search a bit first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594097/javascript-split-string-into-2d-array

Answer (score 2):

The following gets what you're after.

```js
let string = 'Big Ben,www.myurl.com,2020-10-03#Buckingham Palace,www.myurl2.com,2020-15-03#';

let result = string.split('#').filter(function(el) {return el.length !== 0}).map(row => {
     return row.split(',');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you - that's really helpful